# How can I generate a cryptographically secure number in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, cryptography

I am currently using guid `NEWID()` but I know it is not cryptographically secure.

Is there any better way of generating a  cryptographically secure number in SQL Server?

Comment: @Endri Can you clarify what you found lacking? `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM` looks like a perfectly fine answer.

Comment: @CodesInChaos `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM` doesn't generate exactly numbers.. Of course you can convert them to Int, but will the length be the one required? For instance, If i need to generate 8-digit cryptographically secure numbers, how can I use `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM`? Also, are they unique?

Comment: Moreover I'm curious about any other way of generating secure numbers in `SQL`.

Comment: I doubt you'll find a better answer than the one given by Martin Smith as generating anything securely is hard, and CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM would appear to be purpose-built for the job.  If you're really interested you could perhaps look at RFC2898 and use HASHBYTES to build the key derivation function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Interesting question :)

I think this will work: [`CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627408.aspx)

Comment: Oh, this is even usable as a random number source! Random numbers are tedious in SQL Server.

Comment: I aslo need it to be unique. Can I use `Convert(int, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(9, Convert(varbinary, NEWID())))` ?

Comment: @user1761123 - maybe if you could put *all* of your requirements into your question, people might have a chance of answering it. So far, it appears it needs to be unique and of `int` size. Now, what definition of "cryptographically secure" do you want us to use? Is this to be e.g. a nonce?

Comment: I am generating forms and each form must have its own verification code, so that the user can verify its authenticity by pasting the verification code in a TextBox (that's why I thought int was suitable). I don't really have any other reqirements

Comment: It's about the authenticity of the word document, not of the user. In the end of the document there will be written: Verification Code: xxxxxx and then the person that gets the form will check its authenticity by entering the code. But, i can manage this by requiring the user to enter the form id too, and make it like a username-password authentication. thanks for the answer

Answer (score 27):

`CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM` is documented to return a "cryptographic random number".

It takes a length parameter between `1` and `8000` which is the length of the number to return in bytes.

For lengths <= 8 bytes. This can be cast to one of the [SQL Server integer types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187745.aspx) straightforwardly.

```
+-----------+------------------+---------+
| Data type |      Range       | Storage |
+-----------+------------------+---------+
| bigint    | -2^63 to 2^63-1  | 8 Bytes |
| int       | -2^31 to 2^31-1  | 4 Bytes |
| smallint  | -2^15 to 2^15-1  | 2 Bytes |
| tinyint   | 0 to 255         | 1 Byte  |
+-----------+------------------+---------+
```

Three of them are signed integers and one unsigned. The following will each use the full range of their respective datatypes.

```
SELECT 
      CAST(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1)  AS TINYINT),
      CAST(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(2)  AS SMALLINT),
      CAST(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4)  AS INT),
      CAST(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(8)  AS BIGINT)
```

It is also possible to supply a shorter value than the datatype storage.

```
SELECT CAST(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(3)  AS INT)
```

In this case only positive numbers can be returned. The sign bit will always be 0 as the last byte is treated as `0x00`. The range of possible numbers that can be returned by the above is between `0` and  `POWER(2, 24) - 1` inclusive.

Suppose the requirement is to generate some random number between `1 and 250`.

One possible way of doing it would be

```
SELECT  ( 1 + CAST(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1)  AS TINYINT) % 250) AS X
INTO #T
FROM master..spt_values V1,  master..spt_values
```

However this method has a problem.

```
SELECT COUNT(*),X
FROM #T
GROUP BY X
ORDER BY X
```

The first ten rows of results are

```
+-------+----+
| Count | X  |
+-------+----+
| 49437 |  1 |
| 49488 |  2 |
| 49659 |  3 |
| 49381 |  4 |
| 49430 |  5 |
| 49356 |  6 |
| 24914 |  7 |
| 24765 |  8 |
| 24513 |  9 |
| 24732 | 10 |
+-------+----+
```

Lower numbers (in this case `1 -6`) are generated twice as regularly as the others because there are two possible inputs to the modulus function that can generate each of those results.

One possible solution would be to discard all numbers >= 250

```
UPDATE #T
SET    X = CASE
             WHEN Random >= 250 THEN NULL
             ELSE ( 1 + Random % 250 )
           END 
FROM #T
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1) AS TINYINT)) CA (Random)
```

This appears to work on my machine but it is probably not guaranteed that SQL Server will only evaluate the function once across both references to `Random` in the `CASE` expression. Additionally it still leaves the problem of needing second and subsequent passes to fix up the `NULL` rows where the random value was discarded.

Declaring a scalar UDF can solve both those issues.

```
/*Work around as can't call CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM from a UDF directly*/
CREATE VIEW dbo.CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM1 
AS
SELECT CAST(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1) AS TINYINT) AS Random

go


CREATE FUNCTION GET_CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM1()
RETURNS TINYINT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result TINYINT

    WHILE (@Result IS NULL OR @Result >= 250)
            /*Not initialised or result to be discarded*/
        SELECT @Result = Random FROM dbo.CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM1 

    RETURN @Result

END
```

And then

```
UPDATE #T
SET    X  = dbo.GET_CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM1()
```

Alternatively and more straight forwardly one could simply use

```
CAST(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(8)  AS BIGINT) % 250
```

On the grounds that the range of `bigint` is so huge that any bias will likely be insignificant. There are 73,786,976,294,838,208 ways that `1` can be generated and 73,786,976,294,838,206 that `249` can be from the query above.

If even that small possible bias is not permitted you could discard any values `NOT BETWEEN -9223372036854775750 AND  9223372036854775749` as shown earlier.